# Java Object Null Check for method

Tags: java, null-check

I need to create a null check in this formula for the books[i] and I am not entirely sure how to go about this as I am not greatly familiar with null checks and very new at programming. Any and all help is much appreciated!

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books)
{
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
    {
        total += books[i].getPrice();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: `if(books[i] != null)` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you should check if `books` itself isn't null, then simply check whether `books[i] != null`:

```
if(books==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
   if(books[i] != null){
        total += books[i].getPrice();
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried it with null as input value for books?

Comment: @ladislavDANKO Thanks, I initially answer only what OP was asking for, but it is a good comment! Edited my answer.

Comment: Old fashion programming, please update to Java 8, see my comment below. (And the worse is that the answer is incorrect, you don't use double for monetary calculations, that is the job of BigDecimal)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a guard condition to the method to ensure `books` is not null and then check for null when iterating the array:

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books)
{
    if(books == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Books cannot be null");
    }

    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
    {
        if(books[i] != null){
            total += books[i].getPrice();
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 7 You can use `Objects.requireNotNull(object[, optionalMessage]);` - to check if the parameter is `null`. To check if each element is not null just use

```
if(null != books[i]){/*do stuff*/}
```

Example:

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books){
    Objects.requireNotNull(books, "Books must not be null");

    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
        if(null != book[i]){
            total += books[i].getPrice();
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Yoda tests have no value in java: Just code normally as `if (books == null)`

Comment: If you code only in java, they might not have any value, but if you program in more than one language, in which there is a difference, yoda checks are quite important and quickly become a habit. Even more I find them more readable :)

Comment: But this us a java question and nobody uses them in java. It's an industry standard thing.

Comment: ::raises hand:: I use them. Because of habit (one, quite frankly that I don't want to break because I'm a polyglot). And I'd be willing to bet I'm not the only one ;)

Answer (score 2):

If array of Books is null, return zero as it looks that method count total price of all Books provided - if no Book is provided, zero is correct value:

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books)
{
if(books == null) return 0;
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
    {
        total += books[i].getPrice();
    }
    return total;
}
```

It's upon to you to decide if it's correct that you can input null input value (shoul not be correct, but...).

Comment: What is the correct result *is* `0`? In general, exceptions or `null` (via autoboxed return type) are preferred over using magic numbers.

Comment: @BrianRoach It looks that `calculateInventoryTotal(Books[] books)` count total price of a provided Books. So if no Books is provided, total price is zero. So 0 is correct return value in this case, it's definitely no magic number.

Comment: How do you differentiate between a `null` array being passed in, and an array containing one/all book with a price of `0`? The reason throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` is a better choice is because it prevents two different cases (one valid, one not) from producing the same result, and explicitly indicates a programming error.

Comment: @BrianRoach do you need to diferentiate this? in hypothetical method `calculateInventoryCount(Book[] books)` you should need this but if you need total price - in real world price should be zero or higher than zero and doesn't matter if you don't have a book or you have hundreds of books. it depends on your analysis ;-)

Comment: Note that I'm not downvoting your answer or anything, I just think that's it's important to explain to beginners the best-practice approach rather than something that works, right now, for what they're doing. Note the OP has actually accepted the least explanatory answer ::sigh::

Comment: @BrianRoach yes, i see :-) just thinking that in some situations there isn't need to over-exception-throwing, better should be look what method is doing. but of course, for beginer this should be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You simply compare your object to `null` using the `==` (or `!=`) operator. E.g.:

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books) {
    // First null check - the entire array
    if (books == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        // second null check - each individual element
        if (books[i] != null) {
            total += books[i].getPrice();
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: What is the correct result *is* `0`? In general, exceptions or `null` (via autoboxed return type) are preferred over using magic numbers.

Comment: this is only correct check for null values: at first check array and secondly check each element.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for-loop, just add the following line:

```
if(books[i] != null) {
     total += books[i].getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Fair point; if the books parameter is null there'll be a NullPointerException, but I don't believe that is the type of null check that the questioner was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite older. The Questioner might have been turned into an experienced Java Developer by this time. Yet I want to add some opinion here which would help beginners.

For JDK 7 users, Here using

```
Objects.requireNotNull(object[, optionalMessage]);
```

is not safe. This function throws `NullPointerException` if it finds `null` object and which is a `RunTimeException`.

That will terminate the whole program!!. So better check `null` using `==` or `!=`.

Also, use `List` instead of `Array`. Although access speed is same, yet using `Collections` over `Array` has some advantages like if you ever decide to change the underlying implementation later on, you can do it flexibly. For example, if you need synchronized access, you can change the implementation to a `Vector` without rewriting all your code.

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(List<Book> books) {
    if (books == null || books.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    double total = 0;

    for (Book book : books) {
        if (book != null) {
            total += book.getPrice();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Also, I would like to upvote @1ac0 answer.
We should understand and consider the purpose of the method too while writing. Calling method could have further logics to implement based on the called method's returned data.

Also if you are coding with JDK 8, It has introduced a new way to handle null check and protect the code from `NullPointerException`. It defined a new class called `Optional`. [Have a look at this for detail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)

Finally, Pardon my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] arrayBooks) {

    final AtomicReference<BigDecimal> total = new AtomicReference<>(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    Optional.ofNullable(arrayBooks).map(Arrays::asList).ifPresent(books -> books.forEach(book -> total.accumulateAndGet(book.getPrice(), BigDecimal::add)));
    return total.get().doubleValue();

}
```