# null check with Date object

Tags: java, date

My method takes a Date object. And I am passing a null value.How can I check if the (Date date) date is null or not.I am new in Stackoverflow, If the question is not a good one please don't undergrade the post.

Comment: the == operator comes to mind.

Comment: how about a a simple if check? if(date == null)

Comment: thanks a lot buddies.

Comment: @AndreasFester That other Question is more about the Bitwise OR operator than it is about testing for Null.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thats true - it should nevertheless give some hint on how to do a null check in general. A better answer is probably at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664478/java-object-null-check-for-method. But there are now also many specific answers to OP's concrete question below ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Check if it is null:

```
if (date == null) {...}
```

Check if it is not null:

```
if (date != null) {...}
```

Comment: Tip: Putting the null on the left side helps to avoid accidentally using a single `=` thereby making an assignment rather than a test. Like this: `if ( null == date )` and `if( null != date )`. Also, the null on the left may be easier to read as your brain instantly knows you are doing a null test of something.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you could use an [`Optional<Date>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and check its `empty()` or `isPresent()` methods.

Answer (score -1):

Java Code : Check if date is null

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
        {           
            Date date = showDate();
            //check with if-else statement with equals()
            if ( !date.equals( null ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "hi" );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "hello" );
            }
            //check with if-else statement with = oprator
            if ( date!= null )
            {
                System.out.println( "hi" );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "hello" );
            }
        }

        public static Date showDate(){
            return new Date();

        }
```

Comment: you're first check throws a null pointer exception if the object is actually null. the correct way to check it is with the ==  comparison.

Answer (score -8):

You can check with an if-else statement, like this:

```
if (date.equals(null)) {
    //something
} else {
    //something
}
```

Comment: If your date is null this results in a null pointer exception.